# In VSCode, how can I search for a file name (not contents) recursively below a subdirectory?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the explorer in VSCode, I have many repositories containing, for example, a file called `findme.sh`.  I want to find `findme.sh` (the file **name**) within the `example` repository but NOT in the `notme` repository (assume each repo is cloned into a folder of its name, respectively).  I would like to see all the filename matches of `findme.sh` highlighted visually in the explorer tree.

How can I search for the filename `findme.sh` only within the `example` directory without expanding the entire tree below `example`?

I know I can press `cmd`+`p` (which will run `actions.find`), but this will search all repositories, even when I select (click on) the one repository I care about.  This is not the solution I want.

I know I can run `find` or `locate` or other commands in the shell, but this is not what I want either: I want to select (click on) the directory I want to search below and then find any files that match the name below that directory.

I know I can search **within** file contents below a certain directory and use the `files to include` feature.  That is NOT what I want: I want to search for file **names**, not file contents.

Comment: can you use the fuzzy search (ctrl+p) and type, ex `example/findme.sh`? this works relatively well, but obviously depends on the size of your project, commonality of filenames etc

Comment: @CollinD, that's not a bad option (although not exactly what I'm looking for).  The "select folder, `filesExplorer.findInFolder`" (for searching within file contents) user experience is better (IMO) than having to type the root folder name as part of the search.  IntelliJ has the typeahead match I'm looking for (where the matching entries are highlighted in the folder tree, and you can arrow between them), except you need to manually expand everything.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are looking for is [Advanced tree navigation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_advanced-tree-navigation)

With the **Filter** button you can limit the files shown that match.

The **Filter** button has a new look compared to the documentation and they have added a **Fuzzy Match** option

Comment: I tried it.  This option does not allow me to find what I'm looking for without fully expanding the tree, so this does not answer my question.  For reference, I believe this hotkey is the `list.find` command which is `cmd`+`f` by default on a Mac.

Comment: @GordonFogus So fully expanding the tree IS the problem to get what you want, big deal, find the shortcut key to fully expand the tree

Comment: @GordonFogus If VSC does not do what you want out of the box you can always submit a PR to the repo, You have all the source code. Or write an extension that creates a View that does exactly what you want

Comment: I searched for the hotkey to fully expand the tree, but none appear to do what is needed for your answer to work.  A fully expanded tree is unwieldy anyway.  As for writing the feature myself, that's a good reminder of the benefits of open source software and I will keep that in mind as a possible solution for every issue with every open source program.

Comment: @GordonFogus you can let other people implement it by submitting a feature request at the VSC repo, if you don't want a permanent list you can look at the `pickFile` command of the `Command Variable` extension